# AngularJS: Orderby filter not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm loading the table using ng-repeat. After loading the table I'm calling a javaScript function to Freeze the header row and the first column of the table. 
That Javascript is dividing table into . After the loading of the table is done, the header row and first column is getting freezed. But the orderBy filter not working. OrderBy will work properly if i dont call the function to freeze. Is there any condition like structure of the table shouldn't be changed for using OrderBy ?

Comment: Could you add some code ?  Providing a plunker would help a lot too.

Comment: one question why don't you use something like ui-grid or any grid and those grids have the sorting in place most of the times

Comment: Can i post the two  version of HTML code for this. One for when im calling the freezing function and other while i'm not calling it  ?

Comment: @SANDEEPV Sure you can

Comment: @user2232187 thank you for ui-grid suggestion